# Подстановка значения имени таблицы во FROM

Tags: sql, sql-server

Данный запрос

```
SELECT TOP 1 '[' + Name + '].[dbo].[AMT]' as name
FROM master.sys.databases
where name like 'CC_%R'
```

выводит одну строку `[CC_..._58R].[dbo].[AMT]`. Эта строка является названием текущей таблицы, с которой мне нужно работать. 
Мне необходимо подставить это строку в поле `FROM` своего запроса. 
Запрос не должен быть функцией, триггером, программой и т.п.
Я пытался сделать так:

```
with R as 
    (SELECT TOP 1 '[' + Name + '].[dbo].[AMT]' as name
    FROM master.sys.databases
    where name like 'CC_%R')

SELECT * FROM R
```

но это не правильно, так `R` - это таблица, а не строка.

Запрос пишу в Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (Microsoft SQL Server 2014).

Comment: Это называется "динамический SQL". И он требует определённой массы дополнительных телодвижений. [EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms188332(v%3dsql.105))

Comment: @Akina, да, именно так и можно поступить. Но я ищу вариант, как можно обойтись одним запросом.

Comment: Да нет проблем - формируй строку запроса, которая сливает полученную в динамическом запросе выборку во временную таблицу, выполняй этот запрос  и выгребай из этой таблицы данные.

Answer (score 1):

Коллеги вам уже ответили, но я все же дам вам пример:

```
DECLARE @SQL_Script nvarchar(max);

SELECT @SQL_Script = 'SELECT 1 as [Column]';

exec sp_executesql @SQL_Script;
```

Надеюсь смысл вам понятен, подробнее:
[Динамические инструкции SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql?view=sql-server-2017)